# Playstore installation in Android Studio Emulator 7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Tried installing `com.android.vending` apk but failed with the below error.

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package
>   com.android.vending signatures do not match the previously installed
>   version; ignoring!]

Anyone could suggest me the steps to install playstore in android emulator?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.android.vending signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]` means that the emulator already has this package, and it is signed with another certificate. Note that it is not enough to just install google play APK for it to work.

Comment: You can try uninstalling the previous version of your installed app on the emulator before trying to reinstall, including all cached data and any database information.  If you still get an incompatible error, then make sure your build matches the device.  For example if you have x86 build, you can't install on an armeabi device and vice-versa